# Adding Independent Variables to Prophet Package

Tags: r, forecasting, gam, multivariate-testing

There is an R package called `prophet` which is very good. It is a generalized additive model. The dependent variable is the the metric you are trying to solve and the independent variables are: the growth function, seasonality function, and a variable that will account for things not found in those two variables. I want to be able to add another independent variable. For example:

Let's say I want to solve for Page Views. I have the past nine years worth of data and in this package it will take the seasonality and growth rate into account to solve for this. How would I include another independent variable such as "Temperature"?

This is what the equation looks like behind the scenes:

```
Page_Views = g(t) + s(t) + e(t)
```

I want to add another variable:

```
Page_Views = g(t) + s(t) + Beta(Temperature) + e(t)
```

How would I do this in the prophet package?

Here is a tutorial on how to use the package:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prophet/vignettes/quick_start.html

Data is found here: https://github.com/facebookincubator/prophet/blob/master/examples/example_wp_peyton_manning.csv

```
library(prophet)
m<-prophet(df)
future <- make_future_dataframe(m, period = 365)
forecast <- prophet:::predict.prophet(m, future)
plot(m, forecast)
```

The main question I want to know is: "Is there a way to add an additional independent variable to my generalized additive model in the prophet package?

Thanks, any help would be great!

Comment: I'm not seeing a variable named 'Temperature' in the data that you linked to.

Comment: There isn't one. I'm asking if there was a variable called temperature, would I be able to include it in this package as another independent variable?

Comment: After reviewing help pages for what appear to be the main functions in that package, it appears to be a fairly narrow package and only documents the option to switch between linear and logistic links in a Stan model. The model specification appears to be otherwise fixed. If this is a prototype or demonstration model for which further development is intended, then perhaps the package maintainer will know how to extend it.

Comment: Ok thanks for looking into this. Do you have a recommendation for another R package that can do something like this?

Comment: Two thoughts occurred to me. One was the `forecast` package and the other was to get the source-code for prophet and see if it can be re-implemented in pkg:`rstanarm`. You can get the underlying model specification with `prophet::fit.prophet`

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this. In the meantime, it's definitely not the best route probably but I created an ARIMA model and added the argument xreg() to include independent regressors.

Comment: You might want to provide some code for the next "time-traveler".

Comment: The links do not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently library developers have added an `add_regressor` function, which models external regressors in the linear part of the model. See the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/seasonality_and_holiday_effects.html).

Comment: It seems to only accept boolean-type variables, though, not numerical ones like "Temperature" would be

Comment: @Laurent No, you can add any type of feature. See [here](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/311)

Comment: You can add an extra regressor, but the real problem is adding a continuous variable because for that you need to have future values for the extra regressors also in order to predict future values. This beats the purpose of adding extra regressors.